# Removing UINavigationItem prompt making black space on bottom of navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, prompt, uinavigationitem

I have view controller in my storyboard with prompt text line but when I'm pushing a new view controller without prompt line in the navigation bar i get this (see picture) black space between the navigation bar and the view controller main view.

[image: black area under the navigation bar]

i already tried to remove the prompt using this:

```
    [self.navigationItem setPrompt:nil];
```

but i still having this problem.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Also, dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115821/uinavigationitem-prompt-issue

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work-around for setPrompt. It doesn't animate, so it I'm calling it a work-around instead of a solution. Must be in viewDidAppear, not viewWillAppear.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // This is needed for apple bug with self.navigationItem.prompt
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, removing the prompt in viewWillDissapear before the next view is presented worked for me:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[self navigationItem] setPrompt: nil];
}
```

Comment: I can se this problem - and your solution does not work for me, as the prompt will resize only after the previous controller is displayed, and thus living that gap. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not work for me either, prompt resizes after the previous controller is displayed.  Still leaves the gap.