# UINavigationItem Prompt Issue

Tags: ios, ios7, prompt, uinavigationitem

I'm having a problem with the prompt on a UINavigationItem that I just can't resolve...

I have a master and a detail view controller. When I push from the master to the detail a  prompt is shown on the detail view controller:

[image: prompt]

However, when I pop back to the master view controller, the view isn't resized and the window shows through (the window has been coloured red):

[image: window]

This only happens on iOS7, on iOS6 the view resizes as expected.

I've tried a few things such as setting the prompt to nil in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` but nothing seems to fix it.

If I set the navigation bar in the navigation controller to translucent it does fix this - unfortunately that's not an option.

I've created a very small example project here which demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/InsertWittyName/NavigationItemPrompt

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Quite possible (likely even) that this is an iOS bug. Have you checked 7.1?

Comment: Please pause the application after reproducing and print `po [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow recursiveDescription]`

Comment: Have you tried using Autolayout?

Comment: @AudunKjelstrup Autolayout won't help, as this is the topmost view of the view controller, and navigation controller does not use constraints to layout its views.

Comment: Upvoted for putting the example on github.

Comment: Have anyone tried to run the project in new xcode beta? I also get this message in logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103071/why-am-i-getting-an-uibarbuttonitem-customization-warning

Comment: I have sent a pull request demonstrating a workaround for this bug. See https://github.com/mattneub/NavigationItemPrompt

Comment: I updated my pull request to include labels at the top of the interface, proving that the interface works correctly (after the stupid nav bar resizing has taken place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution I can think of is to subclass the `UIView` of the master, and implement `viewDidMoveToSuperview` to set the frame of the view to be from the navigation bar's height to the end of the superview. Since the navigation bar is not translucent, your job is easier, as you don't have to take into account layout guides and content insets.

A few things to notice. When pushing and popping, the system moves your view controller's view into another superview for the animation and then returns it to the navigation controller's private view hierarchy. Also, when a view goes outside of the view hierarchy, the superview becomes `nil`.

Here is an example implementation:

```
@interface LNView : UIView

@end

@implementation LNView

- (void)viewDidMoveToSuperview
{
    [super viewDidMoveToSuperview];

    if(self.superview != nil)
    {
        CGRect rect = self.superview.bounds;

        rect.origin.y += 44;
        rect.size.height -= 44;

        [self setFrame:rect];
    }
}

@end
```

This is not a perfect implementation because it uses a hardcoded value for the navigation bar's height, does not take into account a possible toolbar, etc. But all these you can add as properties to this view and in `viewDidLoad`, before it starts going into the view hierarchy, set the parameters according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this (overriding `didMoveToSuperview`) however it left the view in an inconsistent size after popping back. How would you suggest I try your alternate  'hide the prompt after the view controller is popped' solution?

Comment: @InsertWittyName Can you explain inconsistent size? I did this in our project and it worked, and our navigation bar was translucent. I removed my other suggestion, I checked and the prompt is apparently linked to the navigation item.

Comment: I assume you mean not translucent. When the view was resized it wasn't the correct size, it was under the nav bar (I tested this by putting a red view on top of the view controller's view, which was a few pixels smaller on all sides). Please feel free to fork the code to demonstrate the fix working.

Comment: Thanks. Initially this still didn't resize the view correctly (using the method in my previous comment) ... however if I change the values from 44 to 64 it works perfectly! Accepting as the answer, thanks again! I can't award the bounty yet, but it will be awarded in 21 hours :)

Comment: @InsertWittyName 64 means status bar + navigation controller. So your view controllers are still extended, just not transparent. Just remember, 64 is the correct value for portrait. In landscape, the navigation bar is shorter. So if you pop in landscape, it should be less.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of the danger with having a constant. I will of course replace it with the appropriate, calculated, value :)

Comment: @LeoNatan the project is now 404. new link?

Comment: @elcuco sorry, I no longer have the project. But my answer explains the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the prompt when the user taps the back button, like this

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    if parent == nil {
        navigationItem.prompt = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists whether your nav bars are opaque or translucent. It sucks that Apple has allowed this heinous bug to plague us for over three years now.

All of these solutions are hacks. My solution is to either A) NEVER use prompts, or B) use them in every single view even if you have to set them to "".

Answer (score 0):

You've given the answer yourself - brilliantly. It's a bug, but checking Translucent avoids the bug. Therefore the solution is to check Translucent and then compensate so that the nav bar looks the way you want.

To do so, make a small black rectangle image and include it in your project. Set the background image of the nav bar to this image. Check Translucent. Problem solved! The nav bar is now black opaque in appearance, but it no longer exhibits the bug.

[image]

Comment: I repeat - you've analyzed the heck out of this bug. Please submit a bug report to Apple using your example project.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort matt, however I can't have the nav bar set as translucent as it affects how each individual view on subsequent view controllers is laid out (i.e. they're underneath the nav bar).

Comment: I did try playing with the values in `edgesForExtendedLayout` but it didn't work as expected. Please show me the changes if you can get it to work using this method.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is. I put labels at the top of the views and they are correctly placed. Sure, the view controller's view as a whole is under the nav bar, but so what? As long as what is in the view is visible and correctly placed, you're fine.

Comment: You are right about `edgesForExtendedLayout` - it just aggravates the bug!

Comment: Look, you need to accept that this is a bug and is not going away. Anything you do will be a workaround and will have shortcomings. Of course the real solution would be to lose the prompt.

Comment: Yes I have accepted that, but I also need a workaround that works!

Comment: @InsertWittyName Nooo, why did you remove the `goto` comment?

Comment: @LeoNatan matt posted again so it was out of context, glad you saw it though :)

Comment: I still think my way also works! I haven't seen why it doesn't.

Comment: Does this only work w/ black?  Trying with another color an always end up with a transparent nav, even when the back image is opaque.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift version:**

```
class PromptViewSideEffect: UIView {

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    if let superview: UIView  = self.superview {
        let rect: CGRect = superview.bounds
        rect.origin.y += 44
        rect.size.height -= 44
        self.frame = rect
        }
    }
}
```